# Why does a curl POST request crash my Catalyst::Controller::REST controller?

Tags: perl, rest, curl, http-post, catalyst

I'm using Catalyst to build a RESTful web service, so I create a Catalyst controller in the usual way

```
script/myapp_create.pl controller MyApp::Controller
```

I then fire up the catalyst test server

```
script/zoo_server.pl -rd
```

So far so good - I can now go to `http://localhost:3000/user` and see the message "Matched MyApp::Controller::User in User."

I then replace the first BEGIN line in lib/MyApp/Controller/User.pm with the following line

```
BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller::REST' }
```

Before doing anything else, I want to check my ability to execute a POST request and watch the response. So in another terminal window, I type

```
curl http://localhost:3000/user --verbose --data "<test><m>whatever</m></test>" -H "Content-Type: text/xml"
```

At this point, since I have not implemented any POST methods, I am expecting to see a "405 Method Not Allowed" response. Instead, what I see from curl is this:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /user HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.6 (i386-apple-darwin10.0.0) libcurl/7.19.6 zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/xml
> Content-Length: 28
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection #0
```

This then appears to crash catalyst's test server. The server does not log anything, but future attempts to contact the server, e.g. doing another GET request to "localhost:3000/user", results in "couldn't connect to host" errors from curl.

I note that this only happens if I use Catalyst::Controller::REST. If I just make a regular controller, POSTing to it does not crash anything. So I'm assuming it happens on the deserialization action, which will be delegated to XML::Simple (as per the default for Catalyst::Controller::REST). Any ideas?

What I eventually want to do, by the way, is create a method like `sub thing :Local :ActionClass('REST') ...`, and a corresponding `sub thing_POST`. My understanding is that POST requests to /user/thing containing XML should then automatically get deserialized and put it into `$c->request->data`, before `thing_POST` is called. The above tests are a preliminary to this - designed to check what happens if *no* POST method is defined. (For what it's worth, I get exactly the same behavior if I create `sub thing` and `sub thing_POST`, and then use curl to issue a POST request to /user/thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined your action *thing* with :Local attribute attached, which means the path which is dispatched is /user/thing (instead of that, you are posting your data to /user). May be you would like to check the [Catalyst Manual - Action Types introduction](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Manual-5.8007/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Intro.pod#Action_types)

Alternatively, if you still experience some problems you could try asking at the official #catalyst irc channel.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the IRC tip. In fact, as I've now clarified by editing the question, I get the same behavior if I post to /user/thing. What I'm seeing appears to be a general tendency of (curl-generated) POST requests to crash any action defined in a Catalyst::Controller::REST object. Posting to /user still generates this effect (due to the default `index` action), but posting to an undefined controller (e.g. `/user/feck/off`) does not (I get a "not found" error instead). And only the REST controller does it. So I'm thinking something's broken in my setup.

Comment: OK, I've tried #catalyst on irc.perl.org, to deafening silence so far... no-one seems to be there. On the plus side, the code I showed works fine on my other machine, suggesting that this may be some kind of installation/configuration snafu.

Comment: #catalyst to the rescue... they have actually been v helpful

Answer (score 2):

I eventually traced this to XML::SAX. Reproducible bug condition:

```
% cat >! test
<test><a>blah</a></test>
% perl -e 'use XML::SAX;my $sp = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser;my $tree = $sp->parse_uri("test")'
Segmentation fault
```

Note that it works fine if the XML is quoted, rather than in a file:

```
% perl -e 'use XML::SAX;my $sp = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser;my $tree = $sp->parse_string("<a><b>test</b></a>");print $tree'
HASH(0x1009c4470)
```

Something wrong with my XML::SAX installation, I guess.

Comment: And, indeed, it appears to be a libxml2 version problem: it works fine on version 2.7.5 and later, the buggy version was 2.7.3. Many thanks to #catalyst and stackexchange for your help!